# IAM - Purpose of role identity in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

On-premise administration of Linux VM's, we create identity like user, group and assign policies to the group identity. We do not think about role identity.

---

In AWS cloud, in addition to creating user & group identity,

we  also create role identity, with permission policies that determine what the identity can and cannot do in AWS.

Role can be for example, service role(EC2->S3) or a simple role.

---

In AWS, What does role identity achieve that user & group identity doesn't?

Comment: I think the main point of the roles is that you can have resources assume roles and you don't have to maintain usernames/passwords or KeyIds/SecretKeys. For example instead of keeping secrets in your source code you lunch EC2 into a role and it automatically have correct permissions. It is much safer, and keys rotated automatically. That way if someone got a hold of your source code they don't get the secret keys along with it.

Comment: @DmitriSandler why didn't we have the necessity to have resources assume roles in an on-premise linux environment? On-premise can have similar environment like efs(/usr), ebs(/sbin) etc..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AWS IAM Role vs Group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36991831/aws-iam-role-vs-group)

Comment: @overexchange, generally on prem environment is rather monolithic (forgive the overused term). This generally means that VMs have longer life span as well as passwords/keys are not rotated at extremely high rate. You would use something like Ansible/Puppet/Chief to maintain configuration among of cluster of VMs and rarely (relative) change it. I would look at Roles as a "Next-Generation" or an "advanced" groups. I am not entirely sure what you mean by "EFS(/usr) and EBS(/sbin) on prem". If you could explain and possibly give me a more specific example I could try assist farther.

Comment: @DmitriSandler On-premise, we store `/home/abc` file system on shared file system and all VM's in the network mount to it. So one VM updating `/home/abc` folder in one VM can see the updates in other VM with same login. This is nothing but similar to EFS in AWS

Comment: @overexchange, Depending on your organization's security requirements and risk mitigation tactics, password/key rotation could be put in place. There are many enterprise solutions that perform password/key management. For example, _LastPass_ allows you to automate password rotation, as well as force your admins to check-in/out passwords, ensuring that passwords are changed on every check-in (or according to your custom policy). Effectively, preventing anyone from holding on to a password for prolonged period of time. [LastPass Features](https://www.lastpass.com/enterprise/enterprise-features)

Comment: @overexchange, My point is that IAM Role is AWS's way to automate key/password management tasks in attempt to improve and simplify your security practices. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @DmitriSandler yes got it

Comment: @overexchange Could you mark the answer below as the answer, if it helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Overview**

As organizations across the world create new security policies that aim to minimize the risk and company exposure. System administrators have to opt-in for more complex administrative tasks related to credential management. AWS IAM Roles is a new tool that administrators can use to reduce administrative overhead related to password/key management. Roles could be looked at as extension of user/group permissions.

**AWS IAM Roles**

Roles allow resources (like EC2) to assume permissions and access resources without storing access keys in your source code. Also Roles automatically rotate keys, to limit exposure in case of key was compromised.

**On Premise**

Many organizations moving toward credential management solutions. Enterprise credential management software usually allows to force users to check-in/out passwords/keys, change passwords/keys on check-in preventing users from holding on to the passwords. Administrators also able to create custom policies to manage all aspect of key/password management. One example is [LastPass](https://www.lastpass.com/enterprise/) having those [features](https://www.lastpass.com/enterprise/enterprise-features).