# When to use an IAM role versus an IAM group for a user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am learning AWS IAM and I understand that an IAM role is meant for a specific AWS resource to access other resources , while IAM groups are a group of users that can be attached to a policy.

I want to understand the scenarios in which the users may be given an IAM role instead  of an IAM group, because from what I understand both have managed policies that can restrict users.

Comment: Required reading: https://aws.amazon.com/iam/faqs/

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36991831/aws-iam-role-vs-group I think this questions will solve your query.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id.html Here are the handy description of the Identities (Users, Groups, and Roles)